# spark.createDataFrame from Pandas DataFrame only copies headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am pretty new to Spark and I am trying to convert a pandas DataFrame to a Spark DataFrame using the below. However the sparkDF has just the header columns. The pandasDF has 161 records but they are not being copied and I cannot understand why.

```
sparkD = spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF)
sparkDF.show()
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data?